# Battery Power Control with MOSFET - One Button FlipFlop

Tags: mosfet, flipflop

I cannot get my head around the circuit below of a Flip Flop SR switch using one push button and only MOSFETs:
The image below seems incomplete probably due to a typo (as R3 is not shown) but I believe R3 should connect Vbatt to R4.

The general concept is that with just one Push Button you are able to toggle the MOSFET Q3 ON and OFF.
I understand that from resting position (C1 discharged), the first push on the Button will bring Q1 (and consequently Q2) to conduction, thus charging C1 to Vbatt.
What I do not understand is what happens next if you push again the Button: Does the C1 bring Q1 gate to Vbatt (thus witching it off)?
I spent hours trying to understand but I am honestly lost.

Any help is appreciated.

Bests

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially, C1 is discharged.
When the button is pressed, the gate of Q1 is pulled low trough C1, turning Q1 on.
This, in turn, turns Q2 on because it's gate is pulled high by Q1.
Q2 keeps Q1 on by pulling Q1's gate low trough R4.
So the 2 FET's keep each other enabled, the circuit is turned on.

When you let go of the button, C1 will charge up trough R1.
So next time you press the button, it will pull Q1's gate high, turning it off.
With Q1 disabled, Q2's gate will now be pulled low by R2, turning it off as well.

C1 can now discharge trough R1 and R2, so next time it's empty again and the cycle can repeat.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the walkthrough. I tried to simulate it on EveryCircuit without success but I believe is due to how they model the MOSFETS. Cheers